# How can I export Pub/Sub messages using a Protobuf schema to a GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm currently publishing messages via a Pub/Sub topic that is using a Protobuf schema. This was working fine as my consumer was able to read and decode these messages using the aforementioned schema.

I now want to create an [export subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber) that instead reads these messages and writes them out to files in a GCS bucket. I want these files to contain those same protobuf messages that I can then read in via a Dataflow job to decode and process them.

I've been able to successfully set up the export subscription to write out files to the GCS bucket using two approaches:

- Explicitly creating a `Write to Cloud Storage` subscription via Cloud Console (file format as text)
- Creating a Dataflow job via the template `Pub/Sub to Text Files on Cloud Storage`

However, in both cases the files created produce unreadable content. When I download these files and try to decode manually using `protoc` (along the schema used to generate the records), I receive the message `Failed to parse input.`.

Naturally, I think the pain point here is in writing out Protobuf messages as text files. Is there a way in which this set up can work while preserving the publisher writing out Protobuf messages?

Comment: Hey @DazWilkin, thanks for the message. That could make sense that they are the generic `PubSubMessage`! I'm having difficulty unpacking it via `protoc` as I need all the imports for `PubSubMessage` in one place. Do you have a nifty command that includes the imports?

Comment: I had a quick look at this. I'm not convinced that this works correctly when using Protobuf-encoded messages. First, the files written to GCS **aren't** `PubSubMessage` but **are** your schema type, apologies for my incorrect hunch. Second, I receive GCS objects comprising newline (`0xA`) delimited wire-format (binary) encoded messages. I'm able to extract individual messages **but** because messages are variable-length and because `0xA` **isn't** uniquely a record delimiter (it could occur as part of a message), I'm unsure how you could reliably parse the GCS objects for protobuf messages.